# Wordpress isn't loading custom javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_home_scripts', 20 );
function _enqueue_home_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'infite_scroll', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bower_port', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/bower.iostope.masonry.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'infite_scroll', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/css/custom.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/custom/javascript.js');
    wp_register_script('mobile-numbers', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/custom/mobile-numbers.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mobile-numbers', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/custom/mobile-numbers.js');
}
```

The problem I am having is with `mobile-numbers` script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log("script loaded");
    jQuery( ".nav-toggle-collapsed" ).on( "click", function() {
       console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

Nevermind the `click` code, I am just trying to get it to print the `"script-loaded"` message and it isn't, so it appears the script isn't being loaded at all. The first time I tested the script (not in its current form) it loaded, and then after that it wouldn't change. I removed the minified code from the old script, but that didn't help.

**UPDATE**

The only related error I have in the console is this - I think it is coming from the minified script with my script in it:

> header-35f05689-0.min.js:9 Currently is loaded jQuery version 3.1.1
>   which is too low for OptimizePress. Please check if you're using
>   WordPress version 3.5 or higher or contact customer support.

**UPDATE**

I downloaded the latest `jquery` and put the file in the same directory as the old one and changed the line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'infite_scroll', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.1.1', true );
```

to:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'infite_scroll', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.1', true );
```

Comment: `wp_register_script('mobile-numbers', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/custom/mobile-numbers.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mobile-numbers');`
When you enqueue a script that has been already registered you only need to use its handle without providing the source again: `wp_enqueue_script('mobile-numbers')` will do fine.

Comment: thanks for your response it still isn't being loaded

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser's console? Also please note `wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_js' ...` you need `wp_enqueue_script` not style for `custom_js`

Comment: thanks for the catch...that was a previous developers mistake...I updated my question with what might be a relevant error

Comment: can `infite_scroll` be used twice? that was also the previous developer

Comment: i changed the top one to `'jquery'` for the name and still not loading

Comment: all the errors are gone too, still no go.

Comment: as long as they have the same handle i.e. `infinite_scroll` only one script will be enqueued. If I were you I would comment all wp_enqueue_scripts except the one for `mobile-numbers` and then strt enabling them one by one and see what happens. Usually you do not need to enqueue jquery since wordpress enqueues it automatically, unless you want to use a particular version of jquery

Comment: i commented them all out and it still wouldn't load

Comment: do you have a link where I can access the website, or are you working locally? And also can you change the priority to 99: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_home_scripts', 99 );`

Comment: im working locally - just so u know, i did successfully load a version of this script once...its just i needed to change it...and after the script was loaded the first time...it wouldn't recognize any of the changes i made...so it is being buggy somehow

Comment: i changed priority to 99 still nothing

Comment: i have tried clearing my browser cache a bunch of times too obviously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167943/discussion-between-omar-tanti-and-ewizard).